# Navigation through link list massive in Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need a script that will navigate through online profiles and return. I have some code that shows me how much online profiles links on page:

```
driver.get("http://mygirlfund.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("somemail");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("somepass");
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-submit")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btn-2i']/a")).click();
// log in
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Online Now!']/../..//a"));
// miracle, have found links of all online profiles
System.out.println(allLinks.size());
for (int i = 1; i < allLinks.size(); i++)
{
    for (WebElement link : allLinks)
    {
        link.click();
        driver.navigate().back();
        // here write a message
    }
    i++;
    // navigating through user profiles
}
```

So I need to click on a link then return to previous (main) page but it only navigates to the first link and returns back.

Comment: You seem to be incrementing i twice. In the case you have only 2 links, it'll only run once

Comment: I have around 25 links. If I will remove `for (int i=1; i<allLinks.size(); i++)`, it will run open just first link too.

Comment: Does it throw any error message? Maybe it can't click the link since the link hasn't loaded yet? Try adding a sleep before the click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that when I update webpage the consequences of profile links is breaking down. So, the decision was to open profile link in new window. Do some action and close it. 
As guys above said using two loops was stupid decision. **This code works for me perfect:**

```
for(WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Online Now!']/../..//a"))){             
            String originalWindow =driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println("Original handle is: "+ originalWindow);
//open link in new window
            act.contextClick(link).perform();
            act.sendKeys("w").perform();

            Thread.sleep(4000);
            for (String newWindow : driver.getWindowHandles())
            {
            driver.switchTo().window(newWindow); 
            System.out.println("NOW THE CURRENT Handle is: "+ newWindow);
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
//here write a message              
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
}
```

**Note:**
When I store found links in variable and use it in loop:

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Online Now!']/../..//a"));
//have found links of all online profiles
System.out.println(allLinks.size());
for (WebElement link : allLinks)
{
    String originalWindow =driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println("Original handle is: "+ originalWindow);
//open link in new window
            act.contextClick(link).perform();
            act.sendKeys("w").perform();

            Thread.sleep(4000);
//continue handling new window
```

My script opens just first founded link perpetually.
May be for someone it will be useful. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

What is the outer `for`-loop for? Why do you initialise `i` with 1 (instead of 0)? Why do you increment `i` twice? The inner loop should be sufficient:

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Online Now!']/../..//a"));
for (WebElement link : allLinks) {
    link.click();
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Alternatively, you could retrieve the web elements one by one in a for loop like this (but this will throw an Exception, if there are less than 25 links):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            String xpath = "//img[@alt='Online Now!']/../..//a[" + (i+1) + "]";
            WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
            link.click();
            //....
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for attempt to help but 1st decision will not help 100%, about 2nd - I do not know. And you are right I should use just 1 loop.